What is the significance of the bizarre lizard-like charm Ralph Bohner uses in "Agatha All Along"?
In the Agatha All Along episode "Familiar by Thy Side" (S01E06), Billy Kaplan encounters Ralph Bohner, also known as "Pietro Maximoff" from WandaVision (portrayed by Evan Peters). The episode reveals that the events of WandaVision and the manipulations by witches Wanda Maximoff and Agatha Harkness have left Ralph psychologically scarred and paranoid about witches.
Before divulging the "full deal" to Billy, Ralph retrieves a peculiar trinket from his coat pocket. He shakes it while making a "wuwuwuwu" sound in what appears to be a ritualistic gesture. The object resembles a taxidermied lizard or small alligator/crocodile with some sticks inserted into it. Given Ralph's paranoia, it's likely some sort of anti-witchcraft charm or protective talisman.


What exactly is this trinket, and what significance and purpose does it hold?

I suspect it's just a generic fetish.

A fetish is an object believed to embody spirits or be inhabited by, or attached to, them. A fetish represents the spirits to its owner and creates a bond between the human and supernatural realms. Usually a doll or carved image, a fetish may also be an animal tooth, snake vertebrae, beautiful stones or even the hut where a witch doctor communes with his spirit guides. Fetishes are widely used in animistic religions. They are often worn as ornamental talismans or amulets, but they are not the same as traditional talismans or amulets, which do not carry inhabiting spirits.

Why a lizard? They are animate, but somewhat alien beings, as opposed to mammals. They preserve well, and generally don't have fur that will eventually wear away. There is a reason for the trope of an apothecary alligator.

I'm sorry, it's a what? What's the etymology there?

"Fetish" as a magical charm is the original sense ~1610. More generic meaning "item of blind devotion" 1837, the sexual meaning 1897. https://www.etymonline.com/word/fetish

I remember having a similar reaction when I saw it in the Shadowrun books as a kid. :-D Same way I was hesitant to talk about "bastard swords" or "assassins" since they both had bad words in them...

@FuzzyBoots: "They all went down to Amster<shhh!>"...

Amster-amster- shhh-shhh-shhh

Side note, Evan Peters may have come up with the lizard, as he "built some of his witch kit".
